# Show that $(x-1)$ and $(y-1)$ are not prime ideals and that the ring of polynomials on the unit circle is not a UFD.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm studying algebra, and I have the following problem:

$R$ is the ring of polynomial functions on the unit circle. Thus $R = \mathbb{R}[X, Y] / (X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$.
Put $x := X + I$, $y := Y + I \in R$.

I want to proof that $(x-1)$ and $(y-1)$ are not prime ideals in $R$ and that $R$ is not a unique factorisation domain.

I have already shown that $x-1$ and $y-1$ are irreducible in $R$, this might be useful in the proof.

I was thinking about proving it with contradiction, since I know that $I$ is a prime ideal iff $R/I$ is a domain. However, nothing seems to get anywhere. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $(x-1) (x+1) = -y^2$.

Comment: In order to prove $y \notin (x-1)$, the intuitive idea for one possible proof would be that $x-1$ has a "zero of order 2" at $(1, 0)$ but $y$ has a "zero of order 1" at $(1, 0)$ so $y$ cannot be a multiple of $x-1$.  A bit more formally, you could say that for every $f \in (X-1, X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$, we have $f(1, 0) = 0$ and $\frac{d}{d\theta}[f(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)] |_{\theta=0} = 0$ whereas the second isn't true for $Y$, so $Y \notin (X-1, X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$ which implies $y \notin (x-1)$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense to me!

Comment: To be a bit more purely algebraic, you could achieve much the same thing by defining a *valuation* of "order at $(1,0)$": define $v(p(x) + q(x) y) := \min(2 v_{x-1}(p), 2 v_{x-1}(q) + 1)$ where $v_{x-1}(p)$ is the number of factors of $x-1$ in $p$ or $v_{x-1}(0) = \infty$ and similarly for $v_{x-1}(q)$.  Then the trick is to show that $v(f+g) \ge \max(v(f), v(g))$ and $v(fg) = v(f) + v(g)$, from which it follows that the set of $f$ such that $v(f) \ge 2$ is an ideal.

Comment: Or come to think of it, I guess that could also be simplified further - it amounts to showing that the set of $p(x) + q(x) y$ such that $x-1 \mid p(x)$ and $x-1 \mid q(x)$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: Or simpler yet: if $y = a(x-1)$, then $a$ can be expressed in the form $p(x) + q(x) y$, so $p(x) (x-1) + q(x) (x-1) y = y$ implies $q(x) (x-1) = 1$, contradiction.

Comment: I like you last version indeed! I have one other question for the first one, so you see that $x-1$ has a zero of order 2 at $(1,0)$ by using polar coordinates $(cos(\theta), sin(\theta))$ right? And so if they have zeros of different orders, $y$ cannot be a multiple of $x-1$? Or is it strictly because $y$ has zero of order LESS than $x-1$'s zero?

Comment: Right, that's the idea behind the $f(1,0)=0$ and $\frac{d}{d\theta}[f(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)] |_{\theta=0}$ condition for $f$ having a zero of order $\ge 2$ at $(1, 0)$.  And yes, it's because $y$ has a zero of order strictly less than $x-1$'s zero that $y$ cannot be a multiple of $x-1$.